# Access $http.post response data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I creating small mobile application using **cordova-ionic**, which is authenticated by remote server which is integrated with **oAuth2**.

First I tried to to get `acccess_token` then using that `access_token` I'm  trying access other resources.

This is how I have tried.

```
function getToken(user){
    var username=user.userName;
    var password = user.password;
    var authResponse;
    var access_token;
    var headers = {
       'Authorization': 'Basic ' + TOKEN_ENDPOINT.basicAuth,
       //'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
    }
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization='Basic ' + TOKEN_ENDPOINT.basicAuth;
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        headers: headers,
        url: 'http://remote/oauth/',
    }).then(function (data, status) {
        if (status == '200') { 
            access_token=data.access_token;
            console.log("Auth.signin.success!")
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
    return access_token;
}
```

This is where I am trying to use `access_token`:

```
var goToProfile=function(user){
    var token = getToken(user);  
    if(token != null){
        $http({
            method:'POST',
            url:(API_ENDPOINT.url+'/profile',user),
            param:{access_token:token}
        }).then(function(result){
            console.log(result.data.success);
            console.log("Successfully signed in");
        })
    }else{
        console.log('dasd');
    }
}
```

So the problem is that the `getToken` method always returns `undefined`.

But in my console I can see the `access_token`. so how can I get the `access_token`.

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to write async code as though it were synchronous.

Comment: Thanks for the resposne. so how can i make it to the synchronous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example and modify your code accordingly

```
$http({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:8081/employee-connect/oauth/token",
    data:  "username=1234567891&password=chaitanya&grant_type=password&scope=read write&client_secret=my-secret-token-to-change-in-production&client_id=employeeConnectapp",
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  })
    .success(function(data) {
      window.localStorage.setItem("token_type", data.token_type);
      window.localStorage.setItem("token", data.access_token);


          $http({
            method: "get",
            url: "http://localhost:8081/employee-connect/api/articles",
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
              'Accept' : 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
              'Authorization' : ''+window.localStorage.getItem("token_type")+' '+window.localStorage.getItem("token")
            }
          })
              .success(function(data) {
                $scope.news = data;
              })
              .error(function(data, status) {
              });

    })
    .error(function(data, status) {
    });
```

Comment: I don't see why he needs to use localStorage, really.

Comment: this is just a basic example I sent of an Ionic app using oAuth2 api created by Jhipster that I created

Comment: you can do it without localStorage but it's better  to have it in localStorage and not use it then send a token call again when we need to fire anothe api call

Comment: Well, he's storing it in memory, which would also be fine

Comment: as I said previously it's JUST AN EXAMPLE which anyone can modify according to the programmers requirement

Comment: @abhi314 Thanks this solution is worked but does this handling the error like Http Bad request (for wrong credentials)

Comment: various HTTP status gives different information that we can use to handle the situation, for eg  HTTP status 401 tells us if the request is Unauthorized [ which mean that the issue lies with the request itself maybe we have missed some thing in the header or the user has expired so the username we are sending is invalid or something along the lines ]

Comment: that is why it's better to handle error this way, but of course if we are programmers if you find a better way which suits your requirement feel free to try them out :D